# How to fix Fallout and RIDL?

Tags: debian, kernel, security, firmware

I installed intel-microcode, but when I use ./spectre-meltdown-checker.sh I get this

```
CVE-2018-12127 aka 'RIDL, microarchitectural load port data sampling (MLPDS)'
* Mitigated according to the /sys interface:  NO  (Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT disabled)
* Kernel supports using MD_CLEAR mitigation:  YES  (found md_clear implementation evidence in kernel image)
* Kernel mitigation is enabled and active:  NO 
* SMT is either mitigated or disabled:  YES 
> STATUS:  VULNERABLE  (Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT disabled)
```

How do I fix it ? I can't understand

```
  sudo ./spectre-meltdown-checker.sh | grep 'CPU microcode is'
[sudo] password for user: 
  * CPU microcode is known to cause stability problems:  NO  (model 0x2d family 0x6 stepping 0x7 ucode 0x710 cpuid 0x206d7)
  * CPU microcode is the latest known available version:  NO  (latest version is 0x714 dated 2018/05/08 according to builtin MCExtractor DB v112 - 2019/05/22)
IBPB is considered as a good addition to retpoline for Variant 2 mitigation, but your CPU microcode doesn't support it
> STATUS:  VULNERABLE  (an up-to-date CPU microcode is needed to mitigate this vulnerability)
```

but it's latest

```
sudo apt install intel-microcode
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
intel-microcode is already the newest version (3.20180807a.2~deb9u1).
```

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but did you reboot after installing `intel-microcode`? Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `sudo ./spectre-meltdown-checker.sh | grep 'CPU microcode is'`?

Comment: @StephenKitt Thank you for help Stephen. Yes, I rebooted. Strange stuff spectre-meltdown-checker says CPU microcode is the latest known available version:  NO and apt say intel-microcode is already the newest version . I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Do you have non-free enabled in the security repo in /etc/apt/sources.list?

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

If not, enable non-free, apt-get update, and install intel-microcode again.  It'll install a new package.  Reboot and try spectre-meltdown-checker again.

Comment: `intel-microcode` is already installed, and `apt` knows what versions are available, which means that `non-free` is already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU needs microcode 0x718 to fix Fallout and RIDL; this was added to `intel-microcode` in [the 20190618 update](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1041473/accepted-intel-microcode-3201906181deb9u1-amd64-i386-source-into-stable-embargoed-stable/), which wasn’t available in your configured repositories when you last updated.

It has now [been pushed as a security update for Debian 9](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/DSA-4447-2), and you should get the upgrade the next time you run

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```

(as root). The corresponding package version is 3.20190618.1~deb9u1.

You’ll need to reboot to apply the microcode update.

Comment: Thank you. I have 2 kernels one from strech-backports (4.19) and one default from strech (4.9). After I installed intel-microcode initramfs updates only 4.19. How to apply intel-microcode fix for 4.9 as well ?

Comment: `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` will update all your kernels.